# Long shadow with fragment shader

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

What's the best/simplest way to generate a long shadow similar to this with a fragment shader?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a good start: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/2D-Pixel-Perfect-Shadows

Comment: Doing some progress: http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=170704094939

Comment: Is this for desktop OpenGL or WebGL?

Comment: @NicolBolas WebGL. It could probably be easier/faster with simple canvas draw routine but it would be nice if I could do it with only a shader. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that in css3 is possible gives me hope: https://codepen.io/hugo/pen/nwivF

Comment: Other beautiful CSS example: https://codepen.io/dariocorsi/pen/jqxERJ